# Loop through JSON with mutliple objects

Tags: java, json

My goal is to add everyone to a hashmap with their name and Id number. ID numbers are returned from an POST request example:

```
[
{
 "participant": {
   "id": 118410525,
   "tournament_id": 8282812,
   "name": "test0",
   "seed": 1,
   "active": true,
   "created_at": "2020-04-02T00:14:44.024-04:00",
   "updated_at": "2020-04-02T00:14:44.024-04:00",
   "on_waiting_list": false,
   "removable": true,
   "participatable_or_invitation_attached": false,
   "confirm_remove": false,
   "invitation_pending": false,
   "display_name_with_invitation_email_address": "test0",
   "display_name": "test0",
   "can_check_in": false,
   "checked_in": false,
   "reactivatable": false,
   "check_in_open": false,
   "group_player_ids": [],
   "has_irrelevant_seed": false
 }
},
{
 "participant": {
   "id": 118410526,
   "tournament_id": 8282812,
   "name": "test1",
   "seed": 2,
   "active": true,
   "created_at": "2020-04-02T00:14:44.038-04:00",
   "updated_at": "2020-04-02T00:14:44.038-04:00",
   "on_waiting_list": false,
   "removable": true,
   "participatable_or_invitation_attached": false,
   "confirm_remove": false,
   "invitation_pending": false,
   "display_name_with_invitation_email_address": "test1",
   "display_name": "test1",
   "can_check_in": false,
   "checked_in": false,
   "reactivatable": false,
   "check_in_open": false,
   "group_player_ids": [],
   "has_irrelevant_seed": false
 }
},
{
 "participant": {
   "id": 118410527,
   "tournament_id": 8282812,
   "name": "test2",
   "seed": 3,
   "active": true,
   "created_at": "2020-04-02T00:14:44.051-04:00",
   "updated_at": "2020-04-02T00:14:44.051-04:00",
   "on_waiting_list": false,
   "removable": true,
   "participatable_or_invitation_attached": false,
   "confirm_remove": false,
   "invitation_pending": false,
   "display_name_with_invitation_email_address": "test2",
   "display_name": "test2",
   "can_check_in": false,
   "checked_in": false,
   "reactivatable": false,
   "check_in_open": false,
   "group_player_ids": [],
   "has_irrelevant_seed": false
 }
}
]
```

I have tried the following

```
JSONObject jsonObject = response.getBody().getObject();
        Iterator<String> keys = (Iterator<String>) jsonObject.keys();
        while (keys.hasNext()) {
            String key = keys.next();
            JSONObject value = jsonObject.getJSONObject("participant");
            String id= value.getString("id");
            System.out.println(id);
        }
```

But however I cannot seem to fix the error as it returns a NullPointer 
I have also tried switching around the participant to be inside the key but I will

Fixed it: solution

```
        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getBody().getArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonObject.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            Iterator keys = object.keys();
            while (keys.hasNext()) {
                Object key = keys.next();
                JSONObject value = object.getJSONObject((String) key);
                String component = value.getString("id");
                System.out.println(component);
            }
        }
```

Comment: you want id as a key and all the information as value in new generated hashmap for each object in json?

Comment: Can you post your complete response

Comment: Use jsonArray object